# Liquid sim disappears when I resize the domain 2.93

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am a blender beginner so bare with me :D
So i am trying to fill a Torus with water. I have added a solid modifier to the torus and applied it. Created a sphere inside the Torus and created a liquid domain and make the torus as an effector.
All worked as a charm at first until i tried to resize the domain on the X axis to make it wider than the torus. When i do that the sims doesnt work any more. I have tried to apply scale, increase the resolution to 128, but in vain.

I have attached the [the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLAifmgyyAQroLGF-SssXF8b8WUEPS1O/view?usp=sharing). I Appreciate your help

PS, when I move the domain around, the sim still works

Comment: Could you please add a few screenshots instead because the blender keeps on crashing whenever I try to open your blend file?

Comment: @Ribbit12 Voila :D  [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MipfwDH4jkzjdQDCgUPPWa-XYyIFpvmZ?usp=sharing)
I have tried to capture all settings, but i reallly have everything on default. As mentioned I have applied a solidify and a subdivision to the torus.

PS, i have also added the blend file, maybe it was corrupt or sthg (using blender 3.93.5)

Comment: @Ribbit12 Thank you :) I have uploaded a new blend file using blender 2.91.2. This one should work i guess. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B-umhiffwblcb7TUy04PVJrVv9Hobv95/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but just reset the FLIP ratio value.Just delete the whole value and retype the value

Comment: Okay, in my case, the sim works only when the domain size on the X axis is smaller than the width of the Torus. I have recreated the scene too many times and always end up with the same result.

Comment: @Ribbit12 I just tried retyping the flip ratio, but still same result.

Comment: I am sorry for asking too much. But could you just take some screenshots of your fluid setting of the domain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130971/discussion-between-ribbit12-and-adam).

Comment: Is there a solution to this ? I'm experiencing the same problem in 3.1... Every time I resize the domain, the sim just stops working, regardless if I apply the scale or not